# Twig ignore Array to string conversion exception

Tags: php, twig

Any way to ignore Array to string conversion exception?

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, [
    'strict_variables' => false,
    'debug' => false,
]);
```

I'am allowing external users to edit their custom html. When saving `{{ somearray }}` is a valid syntax

Comment: Provide an example of how the user custom html is loaded, is it a string?

Comment: of course its array `{{ somearray }}`
my users should use {`% for aa in somearray %} {% endfor %}`

Comment: So what exactly is throwing the exception? The loader? Because you've provided twig code for the user but are showing the twig loader in the original post. Is the exception thrown when the user iterates over an array?

Comment: exception when rendering, when saving {{ somearray }} is a valid syntax

Comment: Right, twig should still continue to render the template even with an error since array to string conversion isn't fatal, it's just a warning. Are you testing this in a development environment which has an error handler like whoops?

Comment: should I use @ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That message is not done by twig, but by php itself, you can see if you try to `echo` an array.

You should not display such messages in production, an important part of setting up a prod server is making sure `display_errors` is off so the user cannot see implementation details of your site.

Comment: as for now using @twig->render